# Verify in another portlet-A whether the portlet-B is deployed or not

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portlet

#### Requirement

1. JSP code in `portlet-A`'s JSP includes another portlet as:

   ```
   <liferay-portlet:runtime portletName="portlet-B_WAR_portletbportlet" />
   ```
2. If portlet-B is undeployed it shows a message - portlet-B is unavailable.
3. We need to check when portlet-B is unavailable and do some other functionality and show some other stuff

#### Question

1. Is it possible to check in portlet-A's JSP if portlet-B is deployed?
2. Is there any API which returns say a boolean `true` or `false` if the portlet is undeployed?
3. Any other idea how this can be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
List<Portlet> portlets = PortletLocalServiceUtil.getPortlets(company.getCompanyId(), false, false);
```

which will list out the deployed portlets and then check whether portlet B is present in that list.

Note: To know more about the parameters required for this method, check [this link](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/PortletLocalServiceUtil.html#getPortlets%28long,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) and the [source-code](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/service/impl/PortletLocalServiceImpl.java#L583).